# Pyspark: How to create a new column based of the existing column

Tags: pyspark

What is the equivalent of this operation in Pyspark?

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC'), 'Set':list('ZZXY')})
df['new_set'] = df['Set']
```

Expected output

```
   Set Type  new_set
0   Z    A    Z
1   Z    B    Z
2   X    B    X
3   Y    C    Y
```

Comment: Just use ```withColumn``` method: ```df = df.withColumn('new_set', F.col('set'))```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.withColumn('new_set', col('set'))
```